Uncaught Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unexpected token "string" of value "/"
I have a PHP code and try to convert to twig template file for Opencart with many convertors, but every time code is not working.
Original code:
<?php
$homepage = "/";
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ($homepage == $currentpage) { ?>
some html here
<?php }
else { ?>
other html here
<?php } ?>

Converted code:
{% set homepage  "/" %}
{% set currentpage  _SERVER.REQUEST_URI %}
{{ _SERVER.REQUEST_URI }}
{% if  homepage == currentpage %}
some html here
{% else %}
other html here
{% endif %}

I try to change the code many times, every time errors happened. The result:

Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unexpected token "string" of value "/" ("end of statement block" expected). And _SERVER.REQUEST_URI does not works.


{% set homepage  "/" %} - where is the = sign? https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/set.html

@CBroe , yes, i added = to line, now error disappered and only _SERVER.REQUEST_URI not works.

Couldn't say, if $_SERVER is directly accessible in your environment, might be that you need to explicitly pass this to your template first?

Ready, i posted on top working code. Thanks!

also the same problem, missing = sign at {% set currentpage  _SERVER.REQUEST_URI %}

It isn't, you would need to pass it to the template. If you are using Symfony (2.1+) you could resort to {{ app.request.uri }}. If you are not using Symfony, consider extending twig and add a custom function which returns the value (or the $_SERVER array)

@DarkBee, where must I post the result? Yes, I forgot to say I added this to opencart controller file: $data['site_url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  -  app.request.uri  is not working, Opencart seems not use Symfony.

After all changes, the working code is:
In controller:
$data['site_url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

In Opencart template file:
{% if site_url == '/' %}
    some html here
{% else %}
    other html here
{% endif %}


@Olivier, yes, you are right, this will made code simplier.
